# Why am I getting this error for maximum recursive calls?

Tags: python, recursion

I am tyring to multiply the values in an array recursively but I get an error after running the following code :

```
def multAll(k,A) : 
    multAllRec(k,A,0)
def multAllRec(k,A,i) : 
    if i<len(A):
        A[i] *= k
    multAllRec(k, A, i + 1)

multAll(10,[5,12,31,7,25])
```

Error : RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: You need to add a base case to return at some point. Every call of `multAllRec` is guaranteed to call itself again so you will always hit the limit. Looks like you want something along the lines of `if i >= len(A): return`

Comment: BTW, you can combine the two functions by giving `i` a default value.

Comment: You are in front of a stack overflow (like the forum's name). As Locke said, you are recursively calling the function `multAllRec` without return, that is what is causing the error.

Comment: thanks,  I modified the function so that it contains  ```def multAll(k,A):
    return multAllRec(k,A,0)
def multAllRec(k,A,i):
    if i >= len(A):
        return A```

Comment: Because `multAllRec()` unconditionally calls itself. This needs to be be done conditionally in order for it to stop doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something to `return` a `value`. Within at list a `Conditional` statement to prevent the *infinite loop* recursive calls.

```
def multAll(k,A) :
    multAllRec(k,A,0)
    return A

def multAllRec(k,A,i) :
    if i<len(A):
        A[i] *= k
        multAllRec(k, A, i + 1)
    else:
        return A    
    

B=multAll(10,[5,12,31,7,25])

print(B)
```

[**Output**]

```
[50, 120, 310, 70, 250]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```py
def mult_all_rec(k, A, i=0):
    if i < len(A):
        A[i] *= k
        mult_all_rec(k, A, i + 1)
    return


some_list = [5, 12, 31, 7, 25]
mult_all_rec(10, some_list)

print(some_list)
```

Here, there's no need for a `multAll` method, this recursion can be done by assigning a default value to `i`, 0. (as in`def mult_all_rec(k, A, i=0):`)

when if not i < len(A), you need to `return`. This is called `base condition`.

Every recursion must have a `base condition`.